# Inserting values in Mysql table if all the columns have different values

Tags: mysql

I am working on a blogging site but problem which I am facing is that, I want to allow user to create a blog if and only if his/her combination of email address, Blog Name and Blog Title is different from any other rows in the table. For example let us consider this table:-

```
Email                          BlogName                                BlogTitle
abc@gmail.com                Coder's world                         What is coding?
abc@gmail.com                Sql world                             What is sql?
```

Now if a user tries to enter a values('abc@gmail.com','Coder's Worlds' ,'What is coding?') in the table again then he/she will not be allowed to do so. But if the user tries to insert different combination of email, BlogName and BlogTitle then he/she will be allowed to do so.

As I am pretty new to Mysql, I don't know how to do this, so please help me to do this. 
My Table structure :-
[image]

Comment: crate a unique index with all the columns

Comment: When you create the table make sure whole three(Email, BlogName, BlogTitle) columns selected as primary key. If it is already done, Please put a screen shot of your table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a unique constraint on the combination of the three columns:

```
ALTER TABLE `blog_table` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`Email`(100), `BlogName`(100), `BlogTitle`(100));
```

This will *also* remove any duplicates which might already exist in your blog table.

Note that this constraint uses only the first 100 characters from each of the three columns to avoid the `#1071-Specified key was too long` error.

Comment: It is giving error:- #1071-Specified key was too long;max key length is 767 bytes

Comment: @Gunjan You can subset the columns to get around this error.

Answer (score 0):

Make those 3 Columns unique.

Here is a example of Making multiple fields composite
ALTER TABLE table ADD UNIQUE ('field_1','field_2', 'field_3');

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (SELECT 1 = 1 FROM Table WHERE Email=@email and BlogName=@blogname and BlogTitle=@blogtitle) THEN
BEGIN
    #return error message do not insert
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
   #insert logic here
END;
END IF;
```

Check if matching record exists in table before inserting using above code